# Adding texture detail to a lowpoly model for 3D print

Tags: subdivision-surface, displacement, 3d-printing

I'm working on constructing 3D printable models from an older game for my brother's birthday. I have the base STL to work with but since this is an older game it's lowpoly and I would like to bring out the "details" from the texture in-game into the printable model. Pretty much I want the printable model to have the appearance of the fur. Any tips or advice on how I may do this would be helpful. I've utilized subdivision surface to make the model smoother and not so lowpoly however it's still very basic. I did some research into displacement mapping and attempted this using a fur texture, however I wasn't able to tweak it to anything usable just a blownup blob no matter what settings I used.
P.s. I am new to 3D modeling but am willing to invest the time to learn techniques required.

Thank you for all your time and help!
[image: Goal Image]
[image: Model Image]

Comment: Have you tried turning down the strength of the displacement modifier?

Comment: Yes, I changed the coordinates to UV and tried the strength modifier down to even 0.01 and it still just distorted the model into a blob unfortunately

Comment: Could you share the blend? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/